# Skype Conference call to skype for business

Tags: skype, conferencing, skype-for-business

I've just tried to set up a video conference call using skype for mac. Before the meeting, I skyped in a number of my skype contacts and had a 4-way video call with no problems.

When it came to the real conference, I was not able to combine the different contacts into a single call. I could call one contact, but then the "Add other contacts to this call" option was not available.

The contacts for the actual meeting have skype for business. Is this the issue? Are there compatibility issues that mean skype users cannot conference call skype-for-business users?

Comment: That would depend on the setup of the company. Are you within the same company?

Comment: No, not part of the same company. I am using normal skype, not skype-for-buisness

Comment: So you're not using a company account? In that case you probably should talk to your IT department as ask them what they set up. There are various configuration options that might enable you to join or not. It would also depend on how you setup the conferenc.

Answer (score 1):

Keep noted that Skype for business (SfB) and Skype for Consumer (SfC) are two different products which only share the name. The infrastructure behind them is different.

So a SfB administrator has a wide range of options to control what his users are able to perform. For example he could enable or disable a federation with SfC. So for example if a user is using SfB but a [federation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skype-for-business-online-federation-and-public-im-conectivity.aspx) with SfC isn´t allowed then this user couldn´t perform VOIP or chats with SfC.

The best way would be to check this kind of issue with the SfB administrator as your options on SfC are limited.